# Is the Inverse Mills Ratio Strictly Decreasing?

Tags: normal-distribution, derivative

As far as I know, the Inverse Mills ratio, $\lambda(x)=\phi(x)/\Phi(x)$, is decreasing in $x$. Thus, I am curious now whether $\lambda(x)$ is in fact strictly decreasing in $x$.

To see this, I derived the derivative of the inverse Mills ratio:
\begin{align*}\lambda(x)&=\phi(x)/\Phi(x) \\[2pt]
 \Rightarrow \lambda'(x)&=\frac{\phi'(x)\Phi(x)-\phi(x)^2}{\Phi(x)^2} \\[2pt]
&=-x\lambda(x)-\lambda(x)^2\quad\because \phi(x)'=-x\phi(x)\end{align*}
Here, I have no idea how to show whether $\lambda(x)<0$ or $\lambda(x)\leq0$.

Thus, is the inverse Mills ratio in fact "strictly" decreasing in $x$?

Comment: This ratio is named for John P. Mills, who wrote about it. Punctuation allowed is a tricky small issue even for people with English as their first language, but strictly Mill's is wrong but Mills ratio would be fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Theorem $1.$ (Sampford)* If $\lambda(x):=\frac{\varphi(x)}{\Phi(x)},$ then $\lambda^\prime(x)\in(-1,0).$**

$\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2} z^2}}{\int^{x}_{-\infty}e^{-\frac{1}{2} z^2}\, \mathrm dz}$  is nothing but the density of a [truncated normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution) with support $z\in (-\infty,x]$. Its [variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution#One_sided_truncation_(of_upper_tail)) is $1-x\lambda(x) -\lambda^2(x). $ This implies $\lambda^\prime(x) >-1.$ And by definition, $\lambda(x) > 0; ~x+\lambda(x)> 0 $ for $x\geq 0.$ This is also [true](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1367026/1074816) if $x< 0.$ The result follows.

$\blacksquare$

---

### Reference:

$\rm [I]$ Some Inequalities on Mill's Ratio and Related Functions, *M. R. Sampford,* The Annals of Mathematical Statistics, Vol. $24, $ No. $1$ (Mar., $1953$), pp. $130-132.$

Comment: (+1) Helpful, but tiny detail: the Sampford paper was wrong in calling this the Mill's ratio. The original paper was Mills, J.P.  1927, Table of the ratio: area to bounding ordinate, for any portion of normal curve. _Biometrika_ 18: 395–400

Comment: I see. Thanks for pointing this out @NickCox. I should have looked into your meta [post](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2814/362671).

Comment: This doesn't really matter in the grand scheme of things, but correct still beats incorrect otherwise!